# Redirect to the last page requested after login in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, redirect

1. HI I have search from where client can either click on keywords
   which is below in search bar or enter a keyword in search window, In
   case first when user click on keywords the search_results opens with
   keywords in URL but when user enter keyword then it just give result
   according to it.
2. So when user not logged in then after some search_result we ask for
   login & on click login button we redirect for login popup from where
   user logged in that time we have to redirect on same page so for
   this I am using two concept one for predefined keywords link which
   come on URL just redirect last URL value in session & after logged
   in redirect to that URL.

3.I need help in keyword enter by user & then logged in so needs to redirect with same keyword page to user.

```
function search_result($adKeyword = null){

    if(!empty($adKeyword) && $adKeyword != ''){

        $this->data['City']['keyword'] = $adKeyword;
    }
    //////////////////Maintain fetch data////////////////////
    if(!empty($this->data)){    
        //pr($this->data);exit;
        if($this->data['City']['keyword'] == 'Name or Area of expertise'){
            $this->data['City']['keyword'] = '';
            $this->set("title_for_layout","Search Result");
        }

        if ( empty($this->data['City']['city_name'])) {

            $this->data['City']['city_name'] = $this->Session->read("Location");
        }

        if($this->data['City']['keyword'] != '')
            $this->set("title_for_layout",$this->data['City']['keyword']." | Search Result");
                       //$request_params = Router::getParams();
                          //$this->Session->write('auth_redirect','/'.$request_params['url']['url']);
                    $this->Session->write('login_referrer',$this->params['url']['url']);
                    $this->Session->write('login_referrers',$this->data['City']['keyword']);
```

above two session variable I am using for redirect after authentication on login

```
    if($this->Auth->user('role_id')== Configure::read('App.Role.Mentee')) {
                        if ($this->Session->check('login_referrer')) {
                                   $loginReferrer = $this->Session->read('login_referrer');
                                   $this->Session->delete('login_referrer');
                                   //prd($loginReferrer);  
                                   $this->redirect(SITE_URL."$loginReferrer");
                                   }
                                  else if($this->Session->check('login_referrers'))
                                   {

                                   $loginReferrers = $this->Session->read('login_referrers');
                                   $this->Session->delete('login_referrers');
                                   //prd($loginReferrers);  
                                   $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'fronts','action'=>'search_result/','$adKeyword' => $loginReferrers));
                                   }
                                  else {
                                  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'fronts','action'=>'index'));
                                  }
```

what happening its not going to else if  statement Please help me

Answer (score 0):

> If they are browsing some pages and asked to login then they should redirect to that page after login

That's exactly [what the Auth component does by default](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L355). As such to get the desired behavior, the login function should look similar to:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Note the use of `$this->Auth->redirect()` which returns the url to redirect the user to, this example is taken directly from [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

To change the default Auth redirect url modify the [loginRedirect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3a%24loginRedirect) property of the auth component (from your beforeFilter, for example).

Comment: HI this is not working ,I am telling you again my scenario like on search_result page we have set a button after some results on screen a button is in bottom to check more so If the user has logged in state that time it will give results otherwise our login popup is opening to log in or register if user don't have. So I need in this case redirect to same page from where he logged in

Comment: Does your above comment say something different than the question? If so, I'm not seeing it - please add extra information _to the question_. If it's "not working" 1) Don't reimplement what the Auth component does just set the loginRedirect as shown in the docs 2) debug and find out why - what is in the session when you login? If you're not linking to an authed action and are instead directly accessing the login action from a public page - that's why the Auth component doesn't set the loginRedirect.

Answer (score 0):

For manually login I have solved my issue,I have added this code to search_result action of my front_controller

```
 $request_params = Router::getParams();
$this->Session->write('auth_redirect','/'.$request_params['url']['url']);
```

And in my user _controller I have just used this session variable:

```
if($this->Auth->user('role_id')== Configure::read('App.Role.Mentee')) {
$this->redirect($this->Session->read('auth_redirect'));
else
                                  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'fronts','action'=>'index'));
```

But it is not solving my problem completely, I want to delete session  value after one time redirect.but for this it is not destroying the router session variable value